# How do I debug what takes a partial to render so long in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (5.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (0.6ms)
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_handover_instruction_fields.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_handover.html.slim (30.7ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_vrd.html.slim (5.2ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_features.html.slim (3.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_description.html.slim (5.2ms)
  CarPhoto Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "car_photos".* FROM "car_photos" WHERE "car_photos"."car_id" = $1  [["car_id", 19]]
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (217.0ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.5ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.1ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.1ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.1ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.0ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.1ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.0ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_photos.html.slim (254.6ms)
  Rendered cars/_edit_js.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered cars/edit.html.slim within layouts/application (356.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash.html.slim (5.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_slideout_nav.html.slim (16.9ms)
  Rendered svgs/_carshare_typeface_blue_small.html (0.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_header_nav.html.slim (20.1ms)
```

Above is an excerpt of the Rails.logger when I render one of the pages in my webapp. I realised some of the partial takes suspciously long to render.

For example

```
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (217.0ms)
  Rendered cars/_photo_fields.html.slim (1.5ms)
```

I want to find out what makes the rendering so long and how i can improve it.

Comment: Have you tried what is described in [Performance Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% benchmark("Showing projects partial") do %>
  <%= render @projects %>
<% end %>
```

looks interesting.

A tip in general, if you have many `@items` don't call `render` each time. This saves you time.

```
@items.each do |item|
  render 'one_item', :item => item
end
```

Instead render one time with a collection for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs and it will show you the database queries being generated. This is usually the first place to look and it will highlight where you can make performance improvements by optimising your queries. The obvious one is to check if you can benefit from N + 1 queries using includes.

There are other steps you can take as well, such as adding indices, using pluck if you only need to get individual attributes, using LIMIT and avoid sorting.